# macport install sbt 0.11.3

Tags: sbt, macports

I need sbt 0.11.3 for my project, however, port install only gives me 0.11.2. How to install sbt 0.11.3 using macport?

```
$ sudo port install sbt
--->  Installing sbt @0.11.2_0
--->  Activating sbt @0.11.2_0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you can contact the person listed as the maintainer of the port. (Do `port info sbt` to find the maintainer). It may however take some time before the maintainer updates the port, or there may be no maintainer assigned (shown as "nomaintainer@macports.org").

Alternatively, you also can file a ticket on [macports trac](http://trac.macports.org/).

But if you need the newer version right away, and do not want to build sbt by hand (configure;make;make install). Then you can create a copy of sbt's portfile in a local portfile repository and update that portfile.

1. Create a local portfile repository: [howto](http://guide.macports.org/#development.local-repositories)
2. Copy the sbt portfile directory (a directory called "sbt" (path "/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/ports/devel/sbt/"), containing the file "Portfile" and directory "files") into your local portfile repository
3. Edit your local sbt Portfile to contain the new sbt version number and checksums.
4. Run `portindex` again in your local portfile repository
5. Install sbt with `port install -s sbt`

This only works if the new version is quite similar to the old one, and no changes to the build process are needed.

I hope this can help.

Answer (score 1):

I updated sbt in MacPorts to 0.12.0 on August 16.  As Vortexfive stated, best is to use MacPorts' trac to request an update.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the sbt you install is only the launcher. If you want to use a different version of sbt, you can specify it in project/build.properties as below:

```
sbt.version=0.11.3
```

Then the 0.11.2 sbt launcher should download sbt version 0.11.3 and you can use it in your project. I tried this on my local machine and it works.

More information about launcher https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Launcher